# Reverse engineering - Is this a cheap 3D distance function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, reverse-engineering

I am reverse engineering a game from 1999 and I came across a function which looks to be checking if the player is within range of a 3d point for the triggering of audio sources. The decompiler mangles the code pretty bad but I think I understand it.

```
// Position Y delta
v1 = * (float * )(this + 16) - LocalPlayerZoneEntry - > y;

// Position X delta
v2 = * (float * )(this + 20) - LocalPlayerZoneEntry - > x;

// Absolute value
if (v1 < 0.0)
    v1 = -v1;

// Absolute value
if (v2 < 0.0)
    v2 = -v2;

// What is going on here?
if (v1 <= v2)
    v1 = v1 * 0.5;
else
    v2 = v2 * 0.5;

// Z position delta
v3 = * (float * )(this + 24) - LocalPlayerZoneEntry - > z;

// Absolute value
if (v3 < 0.0)
    v3 = -v3;

result = v3 + v2 + v1;

// Radius
if (result > * (float * )(this + 28))
    return 0.0;

return result;
```

Interestingly enough, when in game, it seemed like the triggering was pretty inconsistent and would sometimes be quite a bit off depending on from which side I approached the trigger.

Does anyone have any idea if this was a common algorithm used back in the day?

Note: The types were all added by me so they may be incorrect. I assume that this is a function of type bool.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best way to visualize a distance function (a [*metric*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics))) is to plot its unit sphere (the set of points at unit distance from origin -- the metric in question is norm induced).

First rewrite it in a more mathematical form:

```
N(x,y,z) = 0.5*|x| + |y| + |z|          when |x| <= |y|
         = |x| + 0.5*|y| + |z|          otherwise
```

Let's do that for 2d (assume that `z = 0`). The absolute values make the function symmetric in the four quadrants. The `|x| <= |y|` condition makes it symmetric in all the eight sectors. Let's focus on the sector `x > 0, y > 0, x <= y`. We want to find the curve when `N(x,y,0) = 1`. For that sector it reduces to `0.5x + y = 1`, or `y = 1 - 0.5x`. We can go and plot that line. For when `x > 0, y > 0, x > y`, we get `x = 1 - 0.5y`. Plotting it all gives the following unit 'circle':

[image: octagon]

For comparison, here is an Euclidean unit circle overlaid:

[image: with euclidean]

In the third dimension it behaves like a taxicab metric, effectively giving you a 'diamond' shaped sphere:

[image: animated]

So yes, it is a cheap distance function, though it lacks rotational symmetries.

Comment: I think the shape is approximately this: https://readtiger.com/img/wkp/en/Enneagonal_pyramid1.png With another, flipped one, below.

Comment: @Soonts: Yep, except that that one has too many faces and is only half of it :) I'll try render a 3D version.

Comment: I hadn't count, used image search for "octagonal pyramid". OK this one is probably better: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Octagonal_bipyramid.png

Comment: Note that `x + y/2` for `y<x` was a usual way to approximate `sqrt(x^2+y^2)` 30 years ago, with processors available at that time. It might be an inheritance of a older game

Comment: Oh come on, animation and shadows, seriously? +1 *not only* for the extra mile that you went there ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer and the images. Don't know why I didn't think to plot it. Appreciate the breakdown.

Comment: @Soonts Enneagonal Dipyramid